# Throw a checked exception

Tags: java

I need to modify the given method. 'RunTimeException' is UNchecked...
It should throw a checked exception:

```
public class Main {

    public static void method() {
        throw RuntimeException;
    }    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            method();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("RuntimeException");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

**I got error:**

```
Compilation error
Main.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
       throw RuntimeException;
             ^
  symbol:   variable RuntimeException
  location: class Main
1 error
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you want? Actually RuntimeException and all of its sub classes are unchecked ones..

Comment: You have to create an exception instance in order to throw it, so the syntax error can be taken care of by using throw new RuntimeException(“bad things happened”);. I don’t really understand the rest of your post though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest reading tutorial here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html.

Here is the excerpt which relates to your queston

> Generally speaking, do not throw a RuntimeException or create a
> subclass of RuntimeException simply because you don't want to be
> bothered with specifying the exceptions your methods can throw.Here's
> the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to
> recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If. a client
> cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked
> exception.